# Cinnamon desktop background changes to my old Unity background intermittently

Tags: cinnamon

Sometimes when I open a folder on my desktop, my background changes to the background I had when I used Unity, and I can no longer use anything on my desktop. Has anyone gotten this bug before? How have you fixed it? The problem is sometimes fixed by logging out/into my account, and is always fixed when I restart my system.

[GIF of the problem](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/JitteryFlickeringIndusriverdolphin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cinnamon/+bug/1581263

Run this command in Terminal:

```
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

The problem was that Ubuntu was defaulting to Nautilus as the file browser, instead of Nemo.

(on a side note, why are all the file browsers named after things in the ocean?)